# Fixed navbar with animation

Tags: html, css, animation, fixed, nav

I'm trying to make a fixed navbar, that shrinks a bit when you scroll,(something like this: http://themes.muffingroup.com/be/biker/) and i've got the navbar fixed and everything, but I can't get the animation to work properly

Can anyone get me started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be super simple @Christian. Just work with offset() and scrollTop() functions from jQuery lib (if you can).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var NavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;
  var Nav = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > NavTop) { 
      $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('sticky'); 
    }
  };

Nav();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    Nav();
  });
});
```

With regards animation -- transition should do the [trick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)!
Ask if you need example, post your code.

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll to the defined point the navbar get extra class. E.G from site you get:

Before shrink

```
#Top_bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 61px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 30;
    transition:
```

After shrink(scroll to some point):

```
#Top_bar.is-sticky {
     position: fixed!important;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: -60px;
        height: 60px;
        z-index: 701;
        background: #fff;
        opacity: .97;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 97);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

}
```

Also you need some jquery code similar to this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $("#Top_bar").addClass("is-sticky");
    } else {
        $("#Top_bar").removeClass("is-sticky");
    }
});
```